# If function A uses function B and I test function A is it an integration test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, integration-testing

I am currently writing an essay about unit test in JavaScript. I am facing the problem that I suspect my unit test (see Below) is actually an integration test, which of course makes my essay a bit more complicated.

This is what I've got. I am working with mocha and chai (assert):

```
// region Implementation

/**
 * @param {number} i
 * @returns {number} i + 2
 */
function A(i) {
    return B(i + 1);
}

/**
 * @param {number} i
 * @returns {number} i + 1
 */
function B(i) {
    return i + 1;
}

// endregion

// region Test

lt("B(i) returns i + 1", () => {
    assert.equals(B(2), 3);
})

lt("A(i) returns i + 2", () => {
    assert.equals(B(2), 4);
})

// endregion
```

To me, the first test definitely looks like a unit test. Best practices for unit testing left out, it tests a function which in this case is a unit which can't be divided into smaller pieces and in this case it does not depend on any other function.

Function A though relies on function B. The result is, that if I test function A I have to assume that function A is correctly working.

So this got me thinking. Is the second test already an integration test rather than a unit test?

Sincerely
Fabian

Comment: You very rarely have any code which does *not* use any other functions. In functional languages even operators are functions, so there's no code which does *not* use other functions. As such, every test would be an integration test.

Comment: probably, but at some point I think you can realize that there isn't any clear barrier between the two, and talk about "automated tests". Of course, the more isolated and independent your tests are, the more "unitish"  you can call them.

Comment: The way I learned integration test vs unit test is if a component uses a deterministic function, you can still see it as a unit test, however when it is non-deterministic it’s clearly a intregation test

Comment: @RobG Of course, you are right. Sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: A unit test of *A* does not depend on the outcome of *B* being correct, only that it's `1 +` whatever `B(i)` returns. Testing the return value of *B* is a separate test. i.e. the test should be "*A(i) returns B(i) + 1*" (or whatever the appropriate syntax is).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a thin line between unit- and integration tests. If `A` uses `B`, strictly spoken you are testing more than just your unit. On the other hand, if the unit is small enough and an important part of the UUT (Unit under test) is the unit you are calling in `B` I think you still can consider it as a unit test. When I talk about an integration test I am testing a whole chain. Another important thing to keep in mind is what @deceze already mentioned: "you very rarely have any code which does not use any other functions. In functional languages even operators are functions, so there's no code which does not use other functions. As such, every test would be an integration test.".

Lets say we have a system where a user can sign up. Personally, I would test the `register` unit in a unit test. In this situation I could write a stub instead of testing against the real database (and still call it a unit test). Afterwards I would write an integration test that would test if a user can sign up *and* sign in with the newly created account.

The following article, written by Martin Fowler, maybe interesting: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html